# @videogular/ngx-videogular autoplay not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, videogular

I'm having some trouble autoplaying the video when loading the page.
The video source URL is loaded dinamically so I've wrapped vg-player with a div and a ngIf so it shows only when the source URL is not empty.
If I add the autoplay="true" to the video tag when I recompile the first time it works but on every reload of the page after it doesn't work anymore. The video loads correctly but I have to press the play button manually.

I've also tried to implement [APIs](https://videogular.github.io/ngx-videogular/docs/getting-started/using-the-api.html) using the onPlayerReady event but then the subscribe is not fired.

ngx-videogular version: 6.0.0

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in html:

```
<vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)">
  <video>...</video>
</vg-player>
```

in ts, subscribe to loadedMetadata, example:

```
api: VgApiService;
onPlayerReady(source: VgApiService) {
this.api = source;
this.api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.loadedMetadata.subscribe(this.play.bind(this))
}
play() {
this.api.play();
}
```